# LD_PRELOAD with setuid binary

Tags: linux, setuid, ld-preload

I am trying to use `LD_PRELOAD` to preload a library with an application that has setuid permissions. Tried `LD_PRELOAD` at first, and it seemed like it was being ignored with the setuid binary, though it was working when I tried it with others like `ls`, `dir` etc.

From the documentation of LD_PRELOAD:

```
   LD_PRELOAD
          A whitespace-separated list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared
          libraries to be loaded before all others.  This can be used to
          selectively override functions in other shared libraries.  For set-
          user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, only libraries in the standard
          search directories that are also set-user-ID will be loaded.
```

I tried to put the library in `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, and `/usr/lib64` with setuid permissions as per this documentation above, but it still doesnt seem to work. If I dont give `LD_PRELOAD` a path in the case where I have the library in the standard dirs with setuid, it cannot seem to find the library. If I give it the path, it does not do anything.

The setuid binary is a root permissions binary that runs in a non root user shell. Any thoughts? Not sure if I am missing a path, an environment variable, or I am misunderstanding the documentation above.

Permissions are as follows:

Library:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 72580 2012-02-10 07:51
```

App:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 137517601 2012-02-10 

env | grep LD
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib (I added this manually myself, usually LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty)
```

Comment: Are you running SELinux?

Comment: Yes,  Suse enterprise 11.1 is what i am currently running..

Comment: It finally worked. In the whole set of tests, I must have messed something up. Putting it in lib64 with the right permissions(setuid) and NOT providing a path to LD_PRELOAD worked. Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 15):

LD_PRELOAD cannot be used with setuid. This is a security feature in linux. 
For reference check [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130711061934/http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23), which goes into the detail on how to use `LD_PRELOAD` to substitute some library calls with custom code, at the example of `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SELinux, this may be due to it. One of the ELF auxiliary vectors that glibc supports is `AT_SECURE`. This particular parameter (which is either 0 by default or 1) tells the ELF dynamic linker to unset various environment variables that are considered potentially harmful for your system. One of these is `LD_PRELOAD`. Normally, this environment sanitation is done when a setuid/setgid application is called (to prevent the obvious vulnerabilities). SELinux also enhanced this sanitation to whenever an application is triggering a domain transition in SELinux (say `sysadm_t` to `mozilla_t` through a binary labelled `moz`, or whatever); SELinux sets the `AT_SECURE` flag for the loaded application (in the example, mozilla/firefox).

The `noatsecure` permission disables the environment sanitation activity for a particular transition. You can do this through the following allow statement (as it would apply on the example above):

```
allow sysadm_t mozilla_t:process { noatsecure };
```

Comment: Is selinux security enhanced linux or suse enterprise?  Im running the latter.  Does what you mentioned still apply for suse enterprise?

Comment: According to [this](http://news.opensuse.org/2008/08/20/opensuse-to-add-selinux-basic-enablement-in-111/) SELinux is an option in SUSE Enterprise starting with 11.1. If you're not using it, however, my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: From what I can see, I am not running Selinux. I dont see any of the usual selinux configuration options. I did see AppArmour, but its disabled as well.

Answer (score 0):

On a system with glibc, you can preload a library using another supported way: by adding the library into `/etc/ld.so.preload`. This one doesn't suffer from the restrictions of `LD_PRELOAD`.

In particular, this way I was able to preload (uselessly, just to demonstrate that it works) `libgtk3-nocsd.so` into `/usr/bin/passwd`, and, when I ran `passwd ruslan`, the library did show up in `/proc/<PID_OF_PASSWD>/maps` while `passwd` was waiting for current password input.

One shortcoming is that you can't do this on a per-app basis like you could with `LD_PRELOAD`. If you really require this, maybe you could change your library to try to check whether it wants to do anything, based on what path to current process binary is (detecting it like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606041/673852)).

Answer (score 0):

`LD_PRELOAD` can't be used with set-user-ID/set-group-ID program, except that the et-user-ID/set-group-ID program is running as the **same** real and effective user and group.

For example, after `fork` and before `exec*`, setting

- `setreuid` to the owner of the set-user-ID program
- `setregid` to the group of the set-group-ID program

Answer (score -2):

Install your lib as such:

- location: /lib or /usr/lib
- permissions: root:root
- has setuid and setgid on

Make sure LD_PRELOAD is exported to your environment

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/yourlib.so
$ env | grep LD_PRELOAD  # verify
```

Then run your program.

Comment: It doesnt work, and it applies athe library to _all_ apps. I was trying to use LD_PRELOAD=... appname to just preload it for this app. As an experiment, I copied ls into my own dir, and added setuid permissions to it(chmod u+s ./ls). My library used to work with ls before, doesnt work with this local permissions changed one anymore.:( As another experiment, I tried adding the lib to /etc/ld.so.preload, and it works, but again, its for all apps. I wanted it to work with LD_PRELOAD=.. appname if possible.

Comment: can you edit to show the result of `ls -lad` on your lib and your program, as well as the result of `env | grep LD`?

Comment: Added the edit. Thanks for your help! Just one more clarification, when I put it in /etc/ld.so.preload, my app also seems to work with the lib, it just works for all apps. Maybe some checks the loader does as part of LD_PRELOAD are skipped in the ld.so.preload case. Also, when I sudo and run as root, LD_PRELOAD works with my app, but I cannot run the app as root unfortunately. This was just a quick experiment.