# stdbuf with setuid/capabilities

Tags: c, linux, buffering, setuid, linux-capabilities

I am reading output from another process which generates output (slow and infinite). Because I want to read this data in real-time I use "stdbuf -oL" (line-buffered, data is text). I do not have control of the generating process so I cannot modify the source to force flushing.

So far stdbuf works just fine, however the process uses SOCK_RAW and needs either to be run as root, have setuid(0) or the `cap_net_raw` capability. When running as non-root with setuid or capabilities stdbuf seems to be ignored. Let me demonstrate the problem:

This is a simple writer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
        int i;
        for ( i = 0;; i++){
                fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", i);
                sleep(1);
        }
}
```

And a simple reader:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t n = 0;
        while (getline(&line, &n, stdin) != -1 ) {
                fputs(line, stdout);
        }
}
```

As expected, by executing `./writer | ./reader` nothing shows up until the buffer is filled. Prepending `stdbuf -oL` enables line-buffering and I get the lines into the reader:

```
% stdbuf -oL ./writer | ./reader
0
1
2
...
```

But if I add `cap_net_raw+ep` it stops working:

```
% sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep ./writer
% stdbuf -oL ./writer | ./reader
(no output)
```

The same behaviour is observed when using setuid:

```
% sudo chown root:root ./writer
% sudo chmod +s ./writer
% stdbuf -oL ./writer | ./reader
(no output)
```

I'm interested in understanding why this happens and how I can continue to use stdbuf without running as root. I admit that I do not fully understand what setuid is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: What function is used within getline()?

Comment: The example uses GNU getline (available with -std=gnu99), but the behaviour is the same with fread.

Comment: Have you looked at it with strace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the [stdbuf source code](http://coreutils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/8.0-2/stdbuf_8c-source.html) it looks like it works by setting LD_PRELOAD.  There are of course security concerns using LD_PRELOAD with setuid executables or sudo.

One suggestion I found was to [disable the noatsecure selinux attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232892/ld-preload-with-setuid-binary) for your executable.

Another, simpler, option would be to avoid stdbuf and simply call `fflush(stdout)` from your source code directly.

Comment: Sadly I don't have control of the source for the writer so I cannot modify it. But thanks for the explanation about stdbuf, it makes sense to disallow LD_PRELOAD for setuid.

Comment: There is also a man page for the FreeBSD port of `stdbuf` showing the use of `LD_PRELOAD`: [libstdbuf](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/3/libstdbuf/)

Answer (score 3):

### Solution without `LD_PRELOAD`

You can use the [`unbuffer`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/unbuffer.man.html) utility which is part of the [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) (`expect-devel`) package. `unbuffer` is a very short expect script. It does not need `LD_PRELOAD` because it uses another trick. `expect` creates a pseudo terminal (like `xterm` or `ssh`) so the process executed using `unbuffer` is fooled to think it is writing to an interactive device therefore by default it uses line buffering on `stdout`.

Usage in your case:

```
unbuffer ./writer | ./reader
```

If `stdbuf` works with the program `unbuffer` would work with a high probability too. Because `LD_PRELOAD` poses some limitations `unbuffer` has advantages over `stdbuf`. Contrary to `stdbuf` it will work with these sorts of executables:

- **setuid**
- **with file capabilities**
- **statically linked**
- **not using standard `libc`**

Comment: You mentioned that using a pty make the buffer become a line buffer. What does this really mean? That if I had an infinite line without a `\n`, nothing will ever come out? Or is there some limit? What about turning buffering off completely, so that at most 1 byte exists in the buffer?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Many systems including GNU/Linux try to be ISO C compatible. There are three modes: unbuffered (everything is sent as soon as possible), fully buffered (buffer defined by its size), line buffered (buffers a single line of the text). For the line buffering the buffer still has a fixed size so when it is filled, it is flushed. No buffering "unlimited" of extremely long lines is happening. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf part 7.21.3 Files