# Python 2 Subprocess: Cannot get output from readline

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

I have the following C application

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    /* Go into an infinite loop here. */
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

And I have the following python code.

```
import subprocess
import time
import pprint


def run():
    command = ["./myapplication"]
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        while process.poll() is None:
            # HELP: This call blocks...
            for i in  process.stdout.readline():
                print(i)

    finally:
        if process.poll() is None:
            process.kill()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I run the python code, the stdout.readline or even stdout.read blocks.

If I run the application using subprocess.call(program) then I can see "hello world" in stdout.

How can I read input from stdout with the example I have provided?

Note: I would not want to modify my C program. I have tried this on both Python 2.7.17 and Python 3.7.5 under Ubuntu 19.10 and I get the same behaviour. Adding bufsize=0 did not help me.

Comment: Probably a buffering issue: try adding a flush to the C application.

Comment: It does seem to be a flushing issue, however, is there a way to avoid modifying the C program? Is there a way to run the subprocess as unbuffered?

Comment: I think `Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)` may do the trick.

Comment: I coudlnt get it to work with bufsize=0 however I do understand the intention here... It should work...

Comment: I get the same behaviour on both python 2 and python 3 however I am using python 3.7.5. and python 2.7.17 I would like it to work on both 2 and 3.

Comment: The buffer exists on the side of the C process as well. I don't think you can force other process to flush its buffers, unless you want to get creative (and non-portable and unmaintainable).

Comment: However without the stdout=… the C program does flush its buffer... or at least I think it is the C program and not something else as I can see "hello world" being printed. It seems that adding in the stdout=… changes the behaviour of flushing..

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/12321).  On-site dupe but look to the second answer, not the accepted answer: [Read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications built using the C Standard IO Library (built with `#include <stdio.h>`) buffer input and output (see [here](https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering) for why). The stdio library, like [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html), can tell that it is writing to a pipe not a TTY and so it chooses block buffering instead of line buffering. Data is flushed when the buffer is full, but `"hello world\n"` is not filling the buffer so it's not flushed.

One way around is shown in [Timo Hartmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60309410/674039) answer, using [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) utility. This uses an [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) trick to swap in its own `libstdbuf.so`. In many cases that is a fine solution, but `LD_PRELOAD` is kind of a hack and [does not work in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13644024/674039), so it may not be a general solution.

Maybe you want to do this directly in Python, and there are stdlib options to help here, you can use a [pseudo-tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) ([docs py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html), [docs py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html)) connected to stdout [instead of a pipe](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).  The program `myapplication` should enable line buffering, meaning that any newline character flushes the buffer.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import errno
import os
import pty
import sys

mfd, sfd = pty.openpty()
proc = Popen(["/tmp/myapplication"], stdout=sfd)
os.close(sfd)  # don't wait for input
while True:
    try:
        output = os.read(mfd, 1000)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EIO:
            raise
    else:
        print(output)
```

Note that we are reading *bytes* from the output now, so we can not necessarily decode them right away!

See [Processing the output of a subprocess with Python in realtime](https://tbrink.science/blog/2017/04/30/processing-the-output-of-a-subprocess-with-python-in-realtime/) for a blog post cleaning up this idea. **There are also existing third-party libraries to do this stuff, see [ptyprocess](https://ptyprocess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)**.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to flush buffers in the C program

```
...
printf("hello world\n");
fflush(stdout);
while(1);
...
```

If you don't want to change the C program, you can manipulate the libc buffering behavior from outside. This can be done by using stdbuf to call your program (linux). The syntax is "stdbuf -o0 yourapplication" for zero buffering and "stdbuf -oL yourapplication" for line buffering. Therefore in your python code use

```
...
command = ["/usr/bin/stdbuf","-oL","pathtomyapplication"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
```

or

```
...
command = ["/usr/bin/stdbuf","-o0","pathtomyapplication"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
...
```