# How to get a program location in C

Tags: c

Do you know how to get the absolute location of the current program in C ? I am not talking about the current directory, but the directory where the executable file is placed.

Comment: Do you mean the directory where the executable is placed?

Comment: Yes I do. The executable path is fine too.

Comment: Which Operating system?

Comment: I feel like this might be OS-dependent, as I don't think the C standard mandates anything about programs having to run from a file

Comment: Only a duplicate if he's talking about Windows

Comment: For unix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606041/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-process-in-unix-linux  Either way, it's a dupe.

Comment: The most general way would be the better, but OS specific answers are good too. I need it for Linux, Mac and Windows

Answer (score 4):

C standard doesn't provide a way of doing it; it has to be done using OS-specific APIs. You might as well have a tiny embedded os programmed directly on a chip; what would the program location be, then?

And on normal OSes I think it could be a security vulnerability.

Comment: I don't think the C standard says "you can't get the full path of the executable". I'd suggest re-phrasing this as "this is only possible using OS-dependent APIs". As to "what would the program location be, then": embedded systems often use `int main(void)` exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux use  `readlink /proc/self/exe`

In Windows use  `GetModuleFileName()` with say `hModule = NULL`

Comment: +1 showing actual solutions is way better than saying "it's impossible" (which it clearly isn't).

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not define a way to do that as far as I know. The only way would be to use OS-dependent functions, which means you do it in Linux/Windows/Mac, not "in C".

One way is to get the executable's filename which is **usually** placed in `argv[0]`. But I'm not sure if it is always safe to assume it to be the full path of the executable.

In BusyBox, for example, they use that trick to make a single executable appear as many separate programs, using symlinks. The executable checks what `argv[0]` is, and behaves accordingly.

Comment: Nope, it shows the executable as it was executed (i.e., if you did `./a.out -foo bar`, then `argv[0]` is `./a.out`

Answer (score 0):

You can look at argv[0], but I'm not sure if it's guaranteed to give you a path.

Comment: @nouney On windows 7 x86 it stores full name of executable. Try it yourself. I have MSVC2005.

Comment: @nouney I didn't know either, so it's ok.