# UNIX: set process name when started or view absolute path in 'ps -ef'

Tags: unix, process

I am starting instances of the same script under different directories, but when I `ps -ef` I see:

```
... /bin/bash ./example.sh ...
... /bin/bash ./example.sh ...
```

how can I still call my process by `./example.sh`, and either display the absolute directory path or set my own process name so that I can distinguish the processes running in different directories when I use `ps -ef`

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606041/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-a-process-in-unix-linux), it shows how you can get the full path of a process

but if you want to set a new process name, then you can rename your files to example1.sh, example2.sh ... ,and create a symbolic link 
 ln -s example1.sh example.sh, and each time you want to call a different file change the link.