# How can I get the application path in C?

Tags: c, gtk, filepath

I'm using GTK to create an interface for my C program running Linux.

I'm using this function to load my XML interface:

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, g_build_filename("myInterface.glade", NULL), &error);
```

As long as I'm in the same directory as my compiled file, it works.
But if I'm in another directory, let say a child one and I execute it: `../a.out`, my program doesn't find the file.

So the idea is to first get the program path ("/home/.../program") and to add the file name to get an absolute path.

But I have no idea how can I get the program path. And I'm not sure this is the best idea to make it work.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: On which OS you need this?

Comment: The answers so far do not consider the case when the executbale was started with no path given, but was found by the shell via scanning the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Related if OS is Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/q/606041/694576

Comment: dirname() in libgen.h allows me to get the path of argv[0] and concatenate my file path to it. This was what I needed.

Comment: I've got some code [here](http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/bin/xpost_pathname.c) that tries to do this.

Comment: @luserdroog For Windows you can use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) without any further issues.

Comment: You can't in general (because the C standard does not know about paths or directories). On *some* operating systems, you could use OS specific tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argv[0] contain the relative/full path you ran to run the program.

just scan up to the last '/' and this will be the run dir from your current location

'edit' after some more research, i found this, which works in all cases:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>
int main()
{
  char path[500] = {0};
  int dest_len = 500;
  if (readlink ("/proc/self/exe", path, dest_len) != -1)
    {
        dirname (path);
        strcat  (path, "/");
        printf("path=%s\n", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` contains the name by which the program was called. You cannot rely on the full path being in it.

Comment: This is still abusing the argument vector and unreliable as a solution for the question. argv[0] is just the invoked program name: it might include a relative path, it might include a full path, it might not include any path at all.

Comment: You have a point in that, yet for most cases, it's a good solution. I use it all the time, so if there is some better solution, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

In your case where you are using GTK, it is better to use [`GResource`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GResource.html) and compile `myInterface.glade` directly into your program.