# How to use Quasar Framework and/or Vue3 with Bun.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, bun

Using the `bun create [..]` command, I could create a `react` and a `next` project. It was straightforward following the instructions on the [bun git repository](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun#readme) (update: most instructions can be found at [bun.sh](https://bun.sh)).

But I could not get it to work with `quasar`/`vue`.

I could successfully install `quasar` with bun:

```bash
bun install -g @quasar/cli
```

But when I tried to create a quasar project:

```bash
quasar create [..]
```

I get a message like:

- `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: Permission denied`
- `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

It looks like `quasar` is trying to use the `node` executable instead of `bun`.

Any ideas how can I make it works with `quasar`/`vue`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Bun.js is still missing a few packages like readline. See also here https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/311.

```
bun --bun run quasar
```

Runs quite well and gives an output.

```
bun --bun run quasar build
```

Gives you the following error message.

```
error: Cannot find package "readline" from "/home/<user>/<project>/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/helpers/logger.js"
error: "quasar" exited with code 1 (SIGHUP)
```

I think we still have to wait for a stable v1.0.

**Update 18.01.2023**

With Bun v0.5.0 we are getting a little closer to the goal. Unfortunately the worker_threads support is still missing and therefore quasar build still fails.

[quasar build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xO3X.png)

Comment: `bun --bun run quasar <cmd>` is what I was looking for! worked for me on `bun 1.0.3` and `@quasar/app-vite 1.6.2`, specifically tried with `quasar` commads `add mode bex` and `describe QIcon`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [opened discussion](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/16320) on the Quasar repo, also `Razvan Stoenescu`, the creator of Quasar, [opened a bug](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/16335) for this topic so we can expect tested support in some months

### Update

As replied by Razvan Stoenescu

> Will be available in q/app-vite v1.6 & q/app-webpack v3.11 (backported from the next major version of the CLIs -- unreleased yet)

### Update 2

Since `CLI v2.3.0` Quasar supports Bun as package manager: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/%40quasar%2Fcli-v2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Using `bun 1.0.3` *on a system without `node` installed*, the following works to create a `quasar` project:

```bash
bun install -g @quasar/cli && bun create quasar
```

And you should be able to run quasar without node if you prefix it with `bun run`:

```bash
bun run quasar build
```

**If you have a version of `node` installed and want to avoid using it**, you **MUST** use the [`--bun`](https://bun.sh/docs/cli/run#bun) flag to force the usage of `bun` instead of `node`:

```bash
bun create --bun quasar
bun run --bun quasar build
```

On machines without `node` installed `--bun` seems to be the default behavior.

Create an alias or function in your shell's `.rc` file:

```bash
function quasar() {
  # option A - "do not use node under any circumstances":
  # bun run --bun quasar "${@}"
  # option B - "node is fine to use when I have it"
  bun run quasar "${@}"
}
```

Then either restart your shell or `source` it:

```bash
# bash
source ~/.bashrc
# zsh
source ~/.zshrc
# etc...
```

now you can run `quasar`'s cli with `bun` as you would normally:

```bash
quasar build
```

There may still be some commands that do not work correctly, see the [compatibility tracker](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis).

from the `quasar` side, [`@quasar/cli-v2.30`](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/%40quasar%2Fcli-v2.3.0), [`@quasar/app-webpack-v3.11.0`](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/%40quasar%2Fapp-webpack-v3.11.0), and [`@quasar/app-vite-v1.6.0`](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/releases/tag/%40quasar%2Fapp-vite-v1.6.0) are listed as officially supporting `bun`!

Comment: nah its just wrapping bun around node unless you use `bun --bun`

see `ps -a` output... `quasar` is still running under `node`

```text
90029 ttys011    0:00.01 bun run dev
90030 ttys011    0:00.00 /bin/bash -c bun run lint:fix && bun run quasar dev
90033 ttys011    0:00.00 bun run quasar dev
90034 ttys011    0:00.69 node /Users/dan/test/node_modules/.bin/quasar dev
```

Comment: so, you sort of right. What's interesting about this is that I ran `bun run quasar` on a system that does not even have `node` installed, and when I ran `bun create quasar` and checked `ps aux | grep '[n]ode'`, I saw the `node` process, **however** when I ran [`ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606057/3277592) I found out that it was actually just pointing back to my bun installation, the weirdest part is that `bun --bun create quasar` _failed_ and `bun create quasar` _did not_. You're completely correct when there is a version of `node` installed though.

Comment: update on the last comment, `bun create --bun quasar` works just fine without any `node` installation, so I guess `bun <cmd> <args>` is equivalent to `bun <cmd> --bun <args>` on machines that do not have `node` installed I have created an [issue](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/6215) on their github for failure when `--bun` is  before `create`