# How to check which conda environment is running on Nvidia GPU

Tags: shell, gpu, conda, nvidia, pid

I want to know who is using which GPUs.

For example.

After `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      6260      C   python                           1203MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     19842      C   python                           7735MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A       594      C   python                           1703MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      6260      C   python                           1371MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     19842      C   python                           5343MiB |
```

Here I want know which conda environments are using for each PIDs.
(Because for our team, we use different conda envs)

What I want is

```
PID : 6260 = env1  
PID : 19842 = env2   
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda environment activation is only a state of a shell session. Short of recovering that state from the parent process, the next best thing might be inspecting [the process path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/606057/570918). For example, I can check some like:

```bash
$ top
#   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
#     1 root      20   0    2500    584    520 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.19 tini
#     8 root      20   0    6000   3740   3136 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash
#    18 root      20   0    2616    596    528 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 sh
#    25 root      20   0   11592   8936   5756 T   0.0   0.1   0:00.01 python
#    28 root      20   0    6000   3960   3312 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 bash
#    99 root      20   0    6000   2144   1516 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash
#   100 root      20   0    6000   2332   1700 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash
#   103 root      20   0   23200  19900   7352 S   0.0   0.1   0:00.10 conda
#   104 root      20   0    5868   3572   3236 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 bash
#   116 root      20   0   10776   7228   4744 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 python
# 10743 root      20   0    7860   3604   3096 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 top     

$ readlink -f /proc/25/exe
/opt/conda/bin/python3.9

$ readlink -f /proc/116/exe
/opt/conda/envs/foo/bin/python3.10
```

which are the **base** and **foo** environments, respectively.